# Painter's theorem inside and outside test

Tags: graphics, 3d, visualization, viewport, projection

I have read from Hearn and Baker computer graphics book. I read the test#2 painter's theorem which image is given below. [Painter's theorem of test#2 image from Hearn and Baker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Ds8.jpg)

This image showing surface S is completely behind the surface S', by checking Substitute the coordinates of all vertices of S(x, y,z) into the plane equation of S' and check for the sign. If all vertices of S are inside S' then S is behind S'. (Fig. 1).

i. e. Ax + By+ Cz + D < 0 ,x, y, z are S vertices.

But I have read from [this websites](https://www6.uniovi.es/hypgraph/scanline/visibility/painter.htm) which showing this concepts but in totally opposite manner.
See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO4o4.jpg) I read from that site, which showing opposite thing on same image. This showing
all vertices of S are outside of S'.

i. e. Ax + By+ Cz + D > 0 ,x, y, z are S vertices.

My question is how is it possible Hearn and Baker saying S is completely inside the surface S' but my mentioned website saying S is outside of S' by sign test of plane equation?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70210377/781723, https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/154952/169874, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/198174/82314, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4323082/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked in multiple other locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign of the distance depends on S' orientation. Let me explain what is happening. When you substitute the points of S into the "implicit" equation of the S' plane you get a **signed** distance from the point to the S' plane. That distance is the shortest one because it goes in the direction of the **normal vector** of the S' plane.

Now, there are **two** possible directions for the normal vector  of the S' plane. Lets say you compute the normal vector N using whatever suitable method, then the negaive of that vector -N is also a normal vector to the plane i.e., you can form a valid plane equation using either N or -N.

Usually in computer graphics the sense of normal vector is determined by the order of the vertices of the polygons. If they are clockwise the normal is -N (by convention) and if order is counterclock wise the notmal is N (by convention). Anyway, usually all planes in your space should have the same orientation so you don't need to care about that.

So the discrepance on the sign can be regarded as a difference in orientation of the planes (CW v.s. CCW) or difference in coordinate systems (e.g., right handed v.s. left handed coordinate system). So both are correct under adequate assumptions. In the end, picking an orientation is a tecnicism or implementation detail.

Comment: If I say Ax+By+Cz+D>0 then (x, y, z) is the outside of the plane and then (−A)x+(−B)y+(−C)z+(−D)<0 indicates (x, y, z) inside of the plane ?

Comment: I would say: dot(N,P) + D > 0 indicate that P is at the side where N is pointing to, that can be ingerpreted as outside/inside depending on your implementation. If you need to swap your interpretation of inside and outside then you can flip the sign on both sides of the equation as you did. That is up to your particular application.